# How do you iterate over an array and extract elements based on their data type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, typeof, splice

I'm trying to extract all of the objects from an array using native javascript.  I keep getting one object as the value.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var person1 = { name: "Daniel Machado", life: true };
var person2 = { name: "Marla Singer", life: null };

var array = ["stg", person1, 1, null, person2];


function extractedObj(objToExtract){   
  for(var i = array.length-1; i--;){
    if (typeof array[i] === "object"){
      splicedObj = array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return splicedObj;
};

extractedObj(array);

// the result I'm looking for is: 
// [Object, Object]
// [person1, person2]

// the result I'm getting is:
// [Object]
// [person1]
```

The output is only one object.  I'm trying to pull them all out.  Ideally, I'd like to do this using forEach and/or arrow functions, but anything works.  Not really sure why you have to decrement for splice in this case either.  Have never really understood that, just know that's what many examples show.  If someone could explain that it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `splicedObject` each time through the loop. You need to push the item you're removing onto an array of results.

```js
var person1 = { name: "Daniel Machado", life: true };
var person2 = { name: "Marla Singer", life: null };

var array = ["stg", person1, 1, null, person2];

function extractedObj(array){
  var splicedObj = [];
  for(var i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (typeof array[i] === "object" && array[i] !== null){
      splicedObj.push(array[i]);
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return splicedObj;
};
console.log(extractedObj(array));
```

The reason you need to decrement when splicing is because it adjusts the indexes of all the elements after the one you remove. If you go through the array in the forward direction, then after you remove element `2`, the element that used to be `3` becomes `2`. The next time through the loop, you will increment `i` to `3`, so you'll never check the item that took the place of the old `2`.

By going the other way, the elements that get renumbered are just the ones that have already been tested, so you won't miss anything.

Comment: Ahhh, you need to push it in without overwriting.  Thanks!

Comment: I've added an explanation of why you have to go through the array backwards.

Comment: Have seen that example a lot in my last year of coding, just never understood 100% why it was done that way.  I understand now.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think you have a couple problems in this, actually: Function parameter name mismatch with the reference used inside the function; the loop test causes it to skip index 0; and `typeof null === "object"`, so it would matches on the null while the desired output doesn't include it.

Comment: I noticed this as well when just testing.  It's still not functioning exactly how I was hoping.  I'm trying to return multiple objects (as many as are in the array).  It will pull multiple strings and numbers out if the proper values are put into place, but it's only returning one object.  Any pointers on how to make it return multiple?

Comment: I just added an executable snippet that shows that it returns multiple objects.

Comment: Thanks @barmar.  I'll look into exactly what that means.  I was thinking of doing something like wrapping another if statement  and checking the last index using a method of some sort.  Thought maybe it was something there.  Still very new to the fold.  Thanks again.

Comment: JS functions can't return multiple values, so it returns an array with all the objects you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ES5 there is a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method in Array prototype.

```js
var person1 = { name: "Daniel Machado", life: true };
var person2 = { name: "Marla Singer", life: null };

var array = ["stg", person1, 1, null, person2];

var isObject = function(element) {
  return element && typeof element === "object";
}

console.log(array.filter(isObject));
```

Comment: That's a nice little approach, will definitely keep this in mind.  And, I can use arrow functions!  Yay  Thank you.

Comment: One more question, because I like actually knowing what's going on to improve and not just copy pasting, why does it return element && typeof element?  Why not just return typeof element?  What's happening there?  Just recently learned filter a bit is why I ask.

Comment: `typeof null` is object, so `element && ...` check filter null values away. Note that it will still include empty objects `{}`

Comment: Very useful to know.  Empty objects are fine, just can't have null or undefined.  It's for a pointless little library project I'm trying to do to extract values from an array so that I can feed the numbers in the array to Math.max via the spread operator.  Will keep the null thing in mind.